# MS Build: How Jenkins build applies build parameters to config file?

Tags: git, jenkins, msbuild, wix

My question is regarding MS Build process using WiX Toolset and Jenkins. I am new to both of this. I am working on task to create a build for deployment on staging server. That server has its own credentials.

What I do is:

1. I used WiX to provide build information like build version number. WiX setup has couple of other *.wxs files and Settings.wxi file.
2. Once I am done with WiX, I move to Jenkins and provide required credentials there to apply them to configuration file for that server. Once I hit 'Build', jenkins creates a build which contains an *.msi file.
3. When I install the msi file and check the web.config file, it doesn't show the passed credentials.

Where I am missing ?

Additional Info: I am using Git repository and able to commit, tag and push my code successfully prior starting above process.

Comment: How are you "providing credentials" from WiX to Jenkins? And how are you referencing them in your build?

Comment: I am providing credentials in Jenkins. There is one section called "Configure" where in I provide required credentials. I use WiX to provide build/version number and create application setup.

Comment: Ok. How does your Jenkins configuration reference them?

Comment: I am still exploring the Jenkins to see how it refers configuration files. But for now, I recovered the issue. What I was doing using Git Command Line was creating tag to my committed changes and then to "Push" I was explicitly mentioning repository name (i.e. my case it was 'origin'). I tried to push changes by not mentioning explicit repository name and moved further to create build in Jenkins. And that proved "Luck of Irish".

Comment: @Tony: I found it. Jenkins connects to TFS via TFS url and that way it accesses TFS repository. To refer to configuration file, Jenkins asks a parameter to be passed to create build against. For that it provides options like create build against particular branch or tag. I am passing tag and Jenkins refers to configuration file under that tag. And that is how it applies credentials I passed in Jenkins against {Placeholders} in configuration file.